# Init property in method called in initialization

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to start with Kotlin. I have a question about initializing properties in the init method. I want to init a property in a method I call in the init block. However this gives the error that the property is not initialized. When I set a property in the init method there is no problem:

```
private var rippleColor: Int

init {
    rippleColor = 1;
}
```

When I do it through another method I get the error I described earlier:

```
private var rippleColor: Int

init {
    setDefaultRippleColor(context)
}

fun setDefaultRippleColor(context: Context) {
    val attrs: IntArray = intArrayOf(R.attr.colorControlHighlight)
    var a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs)

    rippleColor = a.getColor(0, Color.RED)

    a.recycle()
}
```

Is it possible to do it like I want to do or is it just not possible?

Comment: Try using private lateinit var rippleColor : Int.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi I tried but lateinit is not allowed on primitive types

Comment: lateinit is not allowed on primitive types

Comment: you can use `by Delegates.notNull()` for primitives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure the property will get initialized then you can set an arbitrary value.

```
private var rippleColor: Int = 0
```

the value of the `rippleColor` is then replaced by `a.getColor(0, Color.RED)` in the `setDefaultRippleColor` method

Comment: that's not true

Comment: @TimCastelijns  Learned something new about Delegates.notNull(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
private var rippleColor: Int = Int.MIN_VALUE

init {
    setDefaultRippleColor(context)
}

private fun setDefaultRippleColor(context: Context){
    val attrs: IntArray = intArrayOf(R.attr.colorControlHighlight)
    val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs)
    rippleColor = a.getColor(0, Color.RED)
    a.recycle()
}
```